# How to correctly send 403 error while testing file upload?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, multer, chai

I'm using Nodejs Express Multer & Mocha Chai for unit testing my API. I'm running into an issue :

I'm trying to test a route without the correct authorization. (I'm using express-jwt)

```
    expressJwt({ secret: publicKey, algorithms:['RS256'] }),
    function(req, res, next) {
      if(PERMISSION_OK) {
        next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).send({ errorMessage: "Permission denied ! Clearance level not high enough !" });
        // We're sending back the 403 error ! but Mocha & chai gets ECONNRESET , Node & Postman gets the error as expected
    }
```

This sample is simpler than the real one, but everything works fine in the authorization part.

So it seems that the .attach() in my tests is waiting the file to be treated, but it won't because we've already send back an Err:403. I'm stuck on this issue for several days now, any help would be nice !

Greetings

BDaniel

Comment: are you including:
expect(res.status).to.equal(200);

Comment: Sure i do in my test.

But that's the problem i'm not able to test the status, because response is made undefined by the error. I only get:

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  response: undefined
}